# iOS NSURLConnection didReceivedData more than one task

Tags: ios, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I have big problem in iOS.
For some reasons,I must use asynchronous,Because I want to pass SSL error.
So,I use NSURLconnection and get response data from Web server in didReceiveData.
and it work very well when I just post one url to server.

But my question is : if I need to post 2 or 3 different url to server in the same time!
then I receive response data in didReceiveData, I think it will be confusion!
How can I know which response's data is belong to which post task??
Have anyone can help me? Please.. thanks.

Comment: Use the `NSURLConnection` parameter of each delegate method to know which connection the response is for.

Comment: rmaddy,can you give me example code to NSURLConnection parameter of each delegate and I need to write different didReceiveData ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to check your `connection` in Delegate methods of `NSURLConnection`. & use two different resposeData.

Example: 
here two connections `connSend` & `connRecieve`

If using connSend

```
NSURL *url = // Your URL
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connSend=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestObj delegate:self];
```

And For other Connection

```
NSURL *url = // Your URL
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connRecieve =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestObj delegate:self]




- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if (connection==connSend) {
        responseSend = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        [responseSend setLength:0];
    }
    else{
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        [responseData setLength:0];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (connection==connSend) {
        [responseSend appendData:data];
    }
    else{
        [responseData appendData:data];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (connSend==connection) {
       NSLog(@"Error in sending");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error in receiving");
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    if (connection==connSend) {
    // Connection send.
    }
    else{
    // Connection recive
     }

}
```

Its better you can create different class for getting different server responce,

Comment: connSend is writed in:
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:connSend];

delegate:self => delegate:connSend   right? thanks

Comment: Make NSURLConnection global.

Comment: NSURLConnection *connSend1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSURLConnection *connSend2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 
right? thanks

Comment: Yes, but declare connSend1 & connSend2 in .h file. so you can compare it in delegate methods,

Comment: I am beginner! Please detailed...sorry

Comment: OK, I try it .. very appreciate ^^